# await generic Task and return the result

Tags: f#

I have function call

```ml
let result = session.Query<Domain.CustomerReadModel>().ToListAsync()
```

which returns `Task<Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList<Domain.CustomerReadModel>>`

How do I "await" this task correctly in F#?

I tried

```ml
async {
   session.Query<Domain.CustomerReadModel>().ToListAsync() |> ignore
}
```

as well as

```ml
let result = session.Query<Domain.CustomerReadModel>().ToListAsync()
  |> Async.AwaitTask
  |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

This seems to compile but I can't use the result and return it:

```ml
session.Query<Domain.CustomerReadModel>().ToListAsync()
    |> Async.AwaitTask
    |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Async.AwaitTask` takes the task, wraps it in an `async` computation, and returns you that computation. Once you have it, you can use it with `let!` or `do!` or `return!` just like any other `async` computation.

```
async {
  let queryAsFsharpAsync = session.Query<Domain.CustomerReadModel>().ToListAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
  let! result = queryAsFsharpAsync 
  ...
}
```

Or without giving the computation its own name:

```
async {
  let! result = session.Query<Domain.CustomerReadModel>().ToListAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
  ...
}
```

Comment: This results in `FSharpAsync<IReadOnlyList<Domain.CustomerReadModel>>`. How can I get `IReadOnlyList<Domain.CustomerReadModel` from it?

Comment: What exactly results in `FSharpAsync<...>`?

Comment: try return! instead of let! ?

Comment: The `result` is of type `FSharpAsync<...>`. I solved in the calling function (inside a Giraffe handler) like this now: `let customers = EventStore.loadCustomerProjections |> Async.RunSynchronously`. Not sure if it's the right way how I'm doing it though.

Comment: That can't be true. `result` can't be of type `FSharpAsync<...>`. Are you sure you're using `let!` and not `let`?